# Retrieve documents specified DocuSign user

Tags: docusignapi

I want to implement method for retrieve documents user by his email and password. For retrieve documents need have email, password, accountId.

Is it possible retrieve accountId any docuSign user by call method [GetMembershipSummary](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Account%20Management%20Service%20API/GetMembershipSummary.htm%3FTocPath%3DAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7CAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Methods%7C_____16)? It is required Administrator permission. How I can get Administrator permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [DocuSign API Walkthroughs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/api-explorer) and more specifically the **Get Documents List & Download Docs** API walkthrough:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeDocuments